# How can I search specific word while editing html tags as HTML with chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to search specific word while editing element as HTML. When I try to search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> hotkey on Chrome developer tools menu, element quit from editing just like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke4rC.jpg

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This currently (as of Chrome 66) doesn't work. You can only search in non-editing mode. Most of the time that should be sufficient, as you can always search for the word by typing it into the search field.

If you explicitly want to search only in text content and not for tag names or attributes, you can do so by entering an XPath like this:

```
//*[contains(text(),"span")]
```

If that doesn't solve your use case, you may [create an enhancement request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools%20search&colspec=ID%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified%20Stars&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids) for allowing to search while being in edit mode.

Comment: Thanks, Mozilla developer tools support " search in editing mode" feature. I decide to use Mozilla instead of chrome.